# Return a list of checked check boxes on button press in PySimpleGUI

Tags: python, python-3.x, pysimplegui

I have a list which can have a variable number of elements which I want the user to be able to select any amount from they want using checkboxes in PySimpleGUI, then after the user presses submit, it returns a list of all the items the user selected. How could I add this to the layout? I'm fairly new to everything concerning UIs and I've looked for similar questions but couldn't find what I was looking for.

Answer (score 0):

There is no good way to link them except by giving them all a key with a common name (or by using a tuple for the key value, see @MikeFromPSG 's comment). For this example, all the checkboxes that I want to be linked will have 'ITEM' in each of their keys. I'll then get a list of all the elements that can have a value in the GUI with `values` from `window.read()` and then use list comprehension to get only the checked values if they have 'ITEM' in their name. I'll also add a condition to not use any elements that have 'PICK' in their name, as that will be added to the elements generated from the user's checkbox picks. I will also add a column to the layout that is not visible where we will use `window.extend_layout` to add the new check boxes. This column will become visible after the user hits `submit`:

```py
import PySimpleGUI as sg
import pandas as pd

layout = [
    [sg.Check('Item 1', key='-ITEM1-'), sg.Check('Item 2', key='-ITEM2-'), sg.Check('Item 3', key='-ITEM3-')],
    [sg.Check('Item 4', key='-ITEM4-'), sg.Check('Item 5', key='-ITEM5-'), sg.Check('Item 6', key='-ITEM6-')],
    [sg.Check('Item 7', key='-ITEM7-'), sg.Check('Item 8', key='-ITEM8-'), sg.Check('Item 9', key='-ITEM9-')],
    [sg.Button('Submit', key='-SUBMIT-')],
    [sg.Column(layout=[[sg.Text("Users's picks")]],key='-CHECK_PICK-',visible=False)]
]

window = sg.Window('Check Box List', layout, size=(300,300), resizable=True,).Finalize()

while True:
    event, values = window.read()
    if event == sg.WIN_CLOSED or event=="Exit":
        break
    elif event == '-SUBMIT-':
        justChecked = [element for element in values if values[element]==True 
                       and 'ITEM' in element and 'PICK' not in element]
        print(justChecked) # Only the checked box
        
        newLayout = []                 # Create an empty list for the user's picks to be appended to 
        for option in justChecked:     # Loop through the user's picks, adding the checked choices to a new layout
            newLayout.append([sg.Check(option, key=f'-{option}_PICK-')])
        window.extend_layout(window['-CHECK_PICK-'], newLayout) # Extend the -CHECK_PICK- column with the new layout
        window['-CHECK_PICK-'].update(visible=True)             # Show the column

    
window.close()
```

List containing only the boxes that were checked (without their value) from `justChecked`:

```
['-ITEM3-', '-ITEM4-', '-ITEM5-', '-ITEM8-']
```

Picture of the GUI and the checked boxes:

[image]

Picture after submit was clicked:

[image]

Comment: Dataframe adds complexity, maybe unnecessarily. Using AllKetsDict directly not recommended. `key_dict` property more portable. Also may not be needed since `values` has all the keys that may be checkboxes already in it.  But, lots of ways to skin a cat, this is one.

Comment: Thank you @MikefromPSG , I've updated the answer as per your suggestion (ie removed `AllKeysDict` as `values` already contains the needed information) I also added the variable `justChecked` which only returns the list of checked boxes' keys (which is probably all OP needed). Agreed that dataframes add complexity and are probably not needed, I just wanted to show some different options. I updated the answer to order these options by relevance to the question

Comment: Oooooo.... I like it... keys can be tuples BTW... I'm spreading the word on this more actively than before. I didn't do a good job of showing enough of them.  `key=('-ITEM-', 0)` is one way they can be used when you have multiple elements filling the same role.  Something to consider for the future  Stressingt this in the new upcoming docs more and newer cookbook recipes.

Comment: @MichaelS. Thank you, but would there be a way to generate a number of checkboxes based on the number of elements in a list, not a pre-defined number of checkboxes?

Comment: How are you grabbing the list from the user?

Comment: Check the update, I am assuming you are getting the list from the user's checked boxes. If not, it should be pretty easy to use the above code and apply the user's list to it (just replace `justChecked` with the user's list in the `for loop`). If @MikefromPSG has more input, he would be the **number 1** source to listen to. You might want to hide the check boxes after `submit` is hit, or inactivate the submit button, or update the column's layout every time submit is pressed (so it doesn't just continuously add check boxes) but the above should get you started.

Comment: This item is closed.... the PySimpleGUI github is best place for a discussion but thought I would chine in here anyway.  G'luck with rest of your project.